# Can we deduce that this sequence converges to zero

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

Let $(x_{k})_{k≥1}$ be a real sequence verifying $x_{k}=0$ infinitely many times. When $x_{k}≠0$, then $x_{k}>0$ and the values of $x_{k}$ decreases to zero when $k$ increases. My **question**: Can we deduce that this sequence converges to zero.

Comment: Yes.  It follows at once from the definition of convergence.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes it is true.

For a given $\epsilon>0$ you can find a $k$ such that for $n\ge k$ we have $$0\le x_k\le \epsilon$$

Thus the sequence $x_n$ converges to $0$